# Convert website to multilanguage?

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem in language conversion. my website language is in English but my client need the website in Turkish language. it is deals website. back end administrator posts deals  in English but in front end the customers needs to display in Turkish. I am using PHP & Mysql to develop this project. how can i convert the page in Turkish any one Help me..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: And where is the question? What have you done? What problem have you encountered?

Comment: http://translate.google.com/translate_tools try this

Comment: are the strings hard coded..?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a parallel set of pages for each language you wish to support.
2. You can simply provide links to the different "language roots" on your main page.
3. Or you can use a PHP script like this, to automatically redirect based on the browser's language:

http://www.willmaster.com/library/automation/alternate-language-redirect.php

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to build your code in a way, which allows multiple languages, you'll have to use something like Google translate.

You could create an link on the page which contains the link to google translate, along with your actual page url.

Answer (score 0):

also, dont forget to set the character set so it can accept both english/turkish:

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
...
<meta charset='utf8'>
```

also your mysql tables should be ready for utf8:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;   # example
   ...
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

or to update them:

```
ALTER TABLE foo CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

in your php (on top):

```
header("Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\n");
```

then you'be ready to add (translated) utf8 in your database.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted - it sounds like good advice to me ;)

Comment: thanx! i also hoped for a comment for downvoting